# Apache/PHP Configuration question - Where else can info.php be disabled besides php.ini?

Tags: configuration, installation, php5, apache-2.2, debugging

Sorry for the bone head Q. but I rarely need to reinstall my server :)

I wish to enable phpinfo() function. My php.ini config file has the disable_functions directive blank--which I [understand is the way](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) to turn this feature off.

Except this directive in my php.ini config *is* blank. Other php files are being served properly. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using proper tags (*<?php* instead of *<?*)?

What happens if you put *display_errors(E_ALL);* in the beginning of the file?

Comment: I'm stupid. The first one... I never use this shortened syntax; however, I also super-rarely edit the config file. Thus the same file worked for the last install, but not the new.